# Trying to pass variables to Send-MailMessage arguments and failing miserably

Tags: email, powershell, command-line

*x-post from SuperUser*

So I have a problem.

I’m trying to write a scripts that pings a list of hostnames in an external .txt file, and send an email alert if one of them goes down. I’m having a few problems with it, but the main one right now, is that I can’t find a way to insert a variable into the subject line or body of the message. The code I’m using to send to email alert now looks like this:

```
send-mailmessage -to "$alertRecipient" -from "$alertSender" -subject "$alertSubject" -body "$alertBody" -smtpServer "$smtpServer"
```

Now, I’ve used a lot of variable values in that command, and they all work to some extent. I’m mostly looking at `$alertSubject` and `$alertBody`. The values of both of those variables are pulled out of another .txt file and are both equal to “$selHost is offline!”.

`$selHost` is the variable I use in the script to be equal to the hostname the script is working on at any given time. If I do `write-host $selHost` pretty much anywhere in the script, I’ll get something like “SomeComputerName” or “192.168.1.123” and its value changes every time the script switches to the next host.

I want the literal value of `$selHost` to be in the message body of the alert when it gets sent out, but the way I have it written, when the alert gets sent it just says “$selHost is offline!” giving me a completely unhelpful level of insight into the nature of the potential problem.

[Pastebin link of my script as it is now.](http://pastebin.com/skKuChZ9)

`Send-Mail-Message` command on line 30, `$selHost` defined on line 23, `$alertSubject` defined on line 10, `$alertBody` defined on line 12.

**TL;DR: I want to embed the value of a variable into the arguments of the `Send-MailMessage` command, but I’m just getting the name of the variable instead and I don’t know what to do.**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with the value of `$selHost`.

When you import a string from a text file, even if it contains something that looks like a variable, it won't be automatically evaluated by PowerShell. You need to do evaluation (string expansion) manually:

```
$alertSubject = (get-content $runPath\config.txt)[1]
$alertBody = (get-content $runPath\config.txt)[2]
...
# Don't to this immediately after string import. You need $selHost to be
# defined by the script first. Otherwise it'll evaluate to $null.
$alertSubject = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($alertSubject)
$alertBody = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($alertBody)
```